# huggingface Transformer Trainer tqdm progress bar not moving at all in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, tqdm

I'm using `disable_tqdm=False` in my trainer args, but the progress bar is not moving and there won't be a summary table after the training is finished. Could you help me with this?

[image]